# Magento 1.9 - Add Ip addres to customer grid

Tags: grid, admin, ip-address, magento-1.9

I want to export the "manage customers" grid, and also want to add the ip addresses of the customers at the end of the grid.

this is the code that is executed when the grid is loaded

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

i have also added a column

```
        $this->addColumn('ip_address', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('IP Address'),
        'default'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('n/a'),
        'index'     => 'remote_addr',
        'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/customer_online_grid_renderer_ip',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sort'      => false
    ));
```

but i dont get any data.

How can i get the customers ip address in the added column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add ip addresses of the customers at the end of the grid :-**

We've to create a custom module :-

I'm taking namespace as Wakar & Modulename  as Customeripaddress :-

1-
**app/etc/modules/Wakar_Customeripaddress.xml**

So first of all we've to **register** this module :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wakar_Customeripaddress>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wakar_Customeripaddress>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**2- app/code/local/Wakar/Customeripaddress/etc/config.xml :-**

In this file we're defining module configuration(Block override,controller override etc).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wakar_Customeripaddress>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wakar_Customeripaddress>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <customeripaddress>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Wakar_Customeripaddress</module>
            <frontName>customeripaddress</frontName>
          </args>
      </customeripaddress>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>
        <rewrite>        
            <wakar_customeripaddress_customer_accountcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from> <!-- Mage_Customer_AccountController  -->
                <to>/customeripaddress/customer_account/</to> <!-- Wakar_Customeripaddress_Customer_AccountController  -->
            </wakar_customeripaddress_customer_accountcontroller>
        </rewrite>
    <helpers>
      <customeripaddress>
        <class>Wakar_Customeripaddress_Helper</class>
      </customeripaddress>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <customeripaddress>
        <class>Wakar_Customeripaddress_Block</class>
      </customeripaddress>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_grid>Wakar_Customeripaddress_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <customeripaddress>
        <class>Wakar_Customeripaddress_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>customeripaddress_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </customeripaddress>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1523689716_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Wakar_Customeripaddress</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1523689716_setup>
      <customerattribute1523689716_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1523689716_write>
      <customerattribute1523689716_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1523689716_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <customeripaddress>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Wakar_Customeripaddress</module>
          <frontName>admin_customeripaddress</frontName>
        </args>
      </customeripaddress>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

**3-app/code/local/Wakar/Customeripaddress/sql/customerattribute1523689716_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

Now we're going to create a customer custom column & during customer registration we'll use this column to save visitor ip address  & later we'll fetch this ip address to show customer ip address via renderer.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customer_ip_address",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "IP Address",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Customer Ip Address"

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customer_ip_address");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**4- 
app/code/local/Wakar/Customeripaddress/controllers/Customer/AccountController.php :-**

Save Customer Ip address during registration:-

```
<?php
require_once "Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php";  
class Wakar_Customercontrolleroverride_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

    public function postDispatch()
    {
        parent::postDispatch();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml', array('controller_action' => $this));
    }

      public function createPostAction()
    {
        $errUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true));

        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
            return;
        }

        /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
            return;
        }

        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();

        try {
            $errors = $this->_getCustomerErrors($customer);

                // Get Visitor Ip address
            if (empty($errors)) {

            if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
            {
             //check for ip from share internet
                    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
            }
             elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
                {
                     // Check for the Proxy User
                    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
                }
                else
                {
                        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                }

                $customer['customer_ip_address']=$ip;  

                $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
                $customer->save();
                $this->_dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer);
                $this->_successProcessRegistration($customer);
                return;
            } else {
                $this->_addSessionError($errors);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = $this->_getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
            } else {
                $message = $this->_escapeHtml($e->getMessage());
            }
            $session->addError($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
        }

        $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
    }


}
```

**5- 
app/code/local/Wakar/Customeripaddress/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php :-**

Add Ip address in customer grid:-

```
<?php
class Wakar_Customeripaddress_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type'  => 'number',
        ));


        /*$this->addColumn('firstname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
            'index'     => 'firstname'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
            'index'     => 'lastname'
        ));*/
        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));

        $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('group', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'width'     =>  '100',
            'index'     =>  'group_id',
            'type'      =>  'options',
            'options'   =>  $groups,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Telephone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Telephone'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_telephone'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_postcode', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ZIP'),
            'width'     => '90',
            'index'     => 'billing_postcode',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_country_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Country'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'country',
            'index'     => 'billing_country_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_region', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('State/Province'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_region',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_since', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Since'),
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'created_at',
            'gmtoffset' => true
        ));



        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('website_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Website'),
                'align'     => 'center',
                'width'     => '80px',
                'type'      => 'options',
                'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteOptionHash(true),
                'index'     => 'website_id',
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('ip_address', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('IP Address'),
        'default'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('N/A'),
        'index'     => 'remote_addr',
        'renderer'  => 'customeripaddress/adminhtml_renderer_location',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sort'      => false
    ));

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**6-
app/code/local/Wakar/Customeripaddress/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/Location.php**

Using renderer to show ip address in the customer grid:-

```
<?php
class Wakar_Customeripaddress_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Location extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {

        // Instance of customer loaded by the given ID
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($row->getData('entity_id'));
                    return $customer['customer_ip_address'] ;

    }
}
```

Hope this will resolve your problem...!!!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but i have a problem at step 5. when i add the code i get an error, it seems that no class is defined. can you tell met what class i need to add to this file to make it work?

Comment: Thanks that worked, but when i look at the grid i see the IP adress column but dont see the ip address, they are empty

Comment: it'll be work from now, means whenever a new customer creates an account you can see there IP address.

Comment: Hello, i have a problem when i try to get to the customer login page, it says "there has been an error prossesing your request" and when i look in the log file i see this error "Controller file was loaded but class does not exist" Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')

Comment: I don't think this error is coming due to my solution, can you please share a screenshot with me?